# how to roll back(?) CCFadeout, CCScaleby and CCBlink? (cocos2d)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

im trying to use CCFadeOut first for my game, which is the very first action

then I want to move onto scales and then blink without the effect of previous actions.

but when i change to the next action, the effect of previous action last..

for example, if i used fadeout before scale, then change to scale, the ccsprite is faded out with momented scale action

So, what i want to do is removing previous action's effect...

can you please give me some sample code for that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sequencing the actions one after another using *CCSequence*?

```
id fadeout = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:2]; 
id scale = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:2 scale:2];       
id blink = [CCBlink actionWithDuration:2 blinks:5];   

CCSequence* sequence = [CCSequence actions:fadeout, scale, blink, nil]; 
[sprite runAction:sequence];
```